# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'organization' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuex, typeerror

The service data comes from mapGetters using vuex store. When I display the values I get the error

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h04HM.png)

I get the error in console, but the data gets displayed anyway. Why does this happen? How can I remove the error

```
<table border="0" id="tab">
             <tr><td >Name </td><td >: {{services[0].organization.name}}</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Name of Organisation </td><td>: {{services[0].organization.organizationName}}</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Email </td><td>: {{services[0].organization.email}}</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Mobile </td><td>: {{services[0].organization.phone}}</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Location </td><td>: {{services[0].organization.address.no}} {{services[0].organization.address.street}} {{services[0].organization.address.locality}} {{services[0].organization.address.state}}</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Zipcode </td><td>: {{services[0].zipcode}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straight forward and simple solution would be to hide `table` until `services[0]` will be available:

```html
<table border="0" id="tab" v-if="services[0]">
```

I suppose the initial state or `services` is empty array that's why when the first component render occurs it shows these errors because `services[0].organization` cannot be accessed at this very moment.

Going further you can define `computed` prop that will return `organization` object with some default values if if don't wish to hide a table at all.

```html
<tr><td >Name </td><td >: {{organization.name}}</td></tr>
```

```js
  computed: {
     organization () {
       if (!this.services[0]) {
          return {
            name: '',
            //  other organization props here
          }
       }
       return this.services[0].organization
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the vue code get executed the first time. **Services[0]** is not available at the very first moment.

> I get the error in console, but the data gets displayed anyway. Why does this happen?

Once the **services[0]** is available, as the two-way data binding works It will update values in the DOM(Document object model). So, this is why your data getting displayed with a warning.

you can simply do here is add **v-if** attribute in the **table** tag.

```
<table border="0" id="tab" v-if"services[0]">
```

For more reference please look into the official docs for MVVM architecture.
[Vue Model](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/#Model)

Answer (score 0):

Check length of services. Try this.

```
<table border="0" id="tab" v-if"services.length > 0">
```